# Elasticsearch: how to write the mapping for a multi-valued field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. Forgive me if this is obvious. Googled it but did not find how to write the mapping for a mutlivalued field (strings). I only found how to write a multivalued document and search on a multivalued field: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_multi_value_fields_2.html

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This explains it http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html

Comment: Dan, could you please post it as an answer? I will select it. Thanks sooooo much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Elasticsearch docs have a page that explains what you want.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: This url returns a 404 page. (2 years later)

Comment: Odd this is the accepted answer. The question is about multi-VALUED fields, not multi fields, which is something very different. 
Risadinhas' answer below explains the difference.

Answer (score 3):

A multivalued field is different from Elastic's `multi_field`. It is described here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

Current documentation mentions multi-fields here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_field_datatypes

A **multivalued** field as I understand it (and I think that is what you meant by it, as well) is one that contains several values that will be searched separately from each other:

Example:

Field `color`, multivalued, `keyword` containing the following values: "black", "blue", "white". When the query contains "white", there will be a match. The score will be different then if you have a whitespace delimited field with three tokens "black blue white" where white comes last.

> In Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated array type. Any field can contain zero or more values by default, however, all values in the array must be of the same datatype.
>   (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)

Elastic just adds values implicitly to fields. There won't be any error handling like in SOLR with an explicit `multiValued=false`. You will have to check during import time if you want to make sure a field is **not** containing a list of values.

If one or more documents have multiple values for a certain field, this field's values are displayed as array in the JSON results no matter how many values there are for a specific document. So the result type of that field is consistent across the index but it is not reflected in the mapping.